# jQuery nested selectors on dynamically added components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html page where I try to calculate the salvage price of a car, I have an inputfield with its list price, and a button where I can add different salvage price calculations dynamically, with javascript

```
    List price: <input type="text" id="listprice"/>
    <input type="button" id="addpricecalc" value="Add"/>
    <div class="pricecalc">
    <input type="text" class="salvagepricepercent"/>
    <input type="text" class="salvageprice"/>
    </div>
```

so every time I press the button, another div of the class pricecalc is being add, with the same components.

The problem I'm having is trying to make the salvagepricepercent and salvageprice fields dependent on each other (every time one changes, the other changes accordingly), with the dynamically added divs. It works fine when I only use 1 pricecalc, however when I add a second it doesn't work anymore.

How would I go on about to fix this with jQuery. I take it I'd have to work with nested selectors, and something to assign the jquery calculating functions to the dynamically added components.

Answer (score 1):

The method I'd suggest for you is to add dynamic change events to the input field (`.live` is great for this), in the event handler you can find the matching field by traversing to the parent and from there searching for the sibling's class name.

You can use something like this (not tested and probably some syntax is broken):

```
$(".salvagepricepercent").live("change",function() { 
 var priceField = $(this).parent().find(".salvageprice");
 //do your calculation here, something like:
  priceField.val(priceField.val() * $(this).val() / 100);
});
```

and the other way around...